# Graphics in PyQtGraph not updating after zoom

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I have the following PyQtGraph program, which makes a red square "move" when moving a slider:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSlider
from pyqtgraph import (
    mkBrush,
    mkPen,
    GraphicsObject,
    QtGui,
    PlotWidget,
)


class SquareItem(GraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.position_picture = QtGui.QPicture()

    def paint(self, p, *args):
        p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.position_picture)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(-5, -5, 20, 10)

    def update_position(self, x):
        self.position_picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.position_picture)
        painter.scale(1, -1)
        painter.setBrush(mkBrush('r'))
        painter.setPen(mkPen(None))
        painter.drawRect(QtCore.QRectF(x, 0, 1, 1))
        painter.end()
        self.informViewBoundsChanged()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Micromouse maze simulator')
        self.resize(600, 600)

        frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(frame)

        self.graphics = PlotWidget()
        self.graphics.setAspectLocked()
        self.item = SquareItem()
        self.graphics.addItem(self.item)

        self.slider = QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider.setSingleStep(1)
        self.slider.setPageStep(10)
        self.slider.setRange(0, 10)
        self.slider.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksAbove)
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.slider_value_changed)
        self.slider.setValue(1)

        layout.addWidget(self.graphics)
        layout.addWidget(self.slider)

        self.setCentralWidget(frame)

    def slider_value_changed(self, value):
        self.item.update_position(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Everything seems to work fine, but if I zoom in/out and then move the slider again the square position is no longer updated (i.e.: the square is not re-drawn).

How can I fix that?

### Updates

- I am using a square to simplify the problem. In reality, I do not only change position, but I can also draw different shapes, so using `setPos()` is not really an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not update the painting if you want to change position, you should only use `setPos()`. the `paint()` function takes `boundingRect()` as a reference so when moving the graph you are moving it in that coordinate system instead of the coordinate system of `PlotWidget`.

```
class SquareItem(GraphicsObject):
    def paint(self, p, *args):
        p.setBrush(mkBrush('r'))
        p.setPen(mkPen(None))
        p.drawRect(self.boundingRect())

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1)

    def update_position(self, x):
        self.setPos(x, 0)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Micromouse maze simulator')
        self.resize(600, 600)

        frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(frame)

        self.graphics = PlotWidget()
        self.graphics.setAspectLocked()
        self.item = SquareItem()
        self.graphics.addItem(self.item)

        self.graphics.setRange(rect=QtCore.QRectF(-10, -10, 20, 20))

        self.slider = QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider.setSingleStep(1)
        self.slider.setPageStep(10)
        self.slider.setRange(0, 10)
        self.slider.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksAbove)
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.slider_value_changed)
        self.slider.setValue(1)

        layout.addWidget(self.graphics)
        layout.addWidget(self.slider)

        self.setCentralWidget(frame)

    def slider_value_changed(self, value):
        self.item.update_position(value)
```

If you are not going to use signals it is advisable to use objects that inherit from `QGraphicsItem` instead of `QGraphicsObject`, for example you could use `QGraphicsRectItem`:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from pyqtgraph import (
    mkBrush,
    mkPen,
    GraphicsObject,
    QtGui,
    PlotWidget,
)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Micromouse maze simulator')
        self.resize(600, 600)

        frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(frame)

        self.graphics = PlotWidget()
        self.graphics.setAspectLocked()
        self.item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.item.setBrush(mkBrush('r'))
        self.item.setPen(mkPen(None))
        self.graphics.addItem(self.item)

        self.graphics.setRange(rect=QtCore.QRectF(-10, -10, 20, 20))

        self.slider = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider.setSingleStep(1)
        self.slider.setPageStep(10)
        self.slider.setRange(0, 10)
        self.slider.setTickPosition(QtWidgets.QSlider.TicksAbove)
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.slider_value_changed)
        self.slider.setValue(1)

        layout.addWidget(self.graphics)
        layout.addWidget(self.slider)

        self.setCentralWidget(frame)

    def slider_value_changed(self, value):
        self.item.setPos(value, 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**update:**

If you want to redraw you should call `update()`:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

from pyqtgraph import (
    mkBrush,
    mkPen,
    GraphicsObject,
    QtGui,
    PlotWidget,
)


class SquareItem(GraphicsObject):
    colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k', 'w', 'FF0', 'AA0', '0AA']
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mColor = SquareItem.colors[0]

    def paint(self, p, *args):
        p.setBrush(mkBrush(self.mColor))
        p.setPen(mkPen(None))
        p.drawRect(self.boundingRect())

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1)

    def update_draw(self, x):
        self.mColor = SquareItem.colors[x]
        self.update()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Micromouse maze simulator')
        self.resize(600, 600)

        frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(frame)

        self.graphics = PlotWidget()
        self.graphics.setAspectLocked()
        self.item = SquareItem()
        self.graphics.addItem(self.item)

        self.graphics.setRange(rect=QtCore.QRectF(-10, -10, 20, 20))

        self.slider = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider.setSingleStep(1)
        self.slider.setPageStep(10)
        self.slider.setRange(0, 10)
        self.slider.setTickPosition(QtWidgets.QSlider.TicksAbove)
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.item.update_draw)
        self.slider.setValue(1)

        layout.addWidget(self.graphics)
        layout.addWidget(self.slider)

        self.setCentralWidget(frame)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do change the painting in my code. I used a simple square to simplify the problem, although I understand this can lead to confusion. I have updated my question. How should I proceed if I cannot simply use `setPos()` then?

Comment: @Peque using setPos() is the best option if you want your item to move, if you provide a [mcve] closest to your problem I could give you an option to use setPos().

Comment: Yeah, maybe including movement in the reduced code example was not a wise decision, it just resulted in a shorter source code. Let us say the object does not move. It simply changes shape (i.e.: it must be redrawn). That is why I am updating the painting. That is a must for this problem. As I said, I updated the question to make it more clear. Sorry for the misunderstanding. :-/

Comment: @Peque 
I have assumed that drawing only affects color, if it is not the best solution it is because you do not give me a closer context with your problem. I do not understand secrecy.

Comment: No secrecy intended on my part. When creating the *minimal* example one might reduce it too much and this may lead to confusion. Even though the drawing changes its shape (as noted in my comment and updated question), it seems calling `.update()` fixes the problem. Thanks, I learned a lot from your answer and it helped me refactor/clean the code too. :-)